# Use conditional logic to call alternative headers in site layout page

Tags: razor, asp.net-webpages

I am trying to find a way to use alternative headers in Razor Web Pages without using two _SiteLayout pages, with each _SiteLayout rendering a different _header page.

I’m trying to achieve this - If the default.cshtml page is called use header-1, if  any other page is called use header-2.

I have tried all sorts of different logic with no joy, including: IsCurrentPage, Request.QueryString, Request.Url; and CurrentPage.Name.

E.G.

```
@if ((Request.QueryString["Default"] == null))
{
       @RenderPage("/shared/_header-1.cshtml") 
}
else
{
      @RenderPage("/shared/_header-2.chtml") 
}
```

And

```
@{
 var pageUrl = this.Request.Url;
}
@if (pageUrl = "http://mycompany/Default.cshtml/") {
@RenderPage("/shared/_header-1.cshtml");
}
else
{
@RenderPage("/shared/_header-2.cshtml");
}
```

Does anyone have a simple method to achieve this please?

Answer (score 0):

Although, I spent a long time on this, not long after posting I found an answer thanks to: [Erik Philips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486912/use-conditional-logic-to-call-alternative-headers-in-site-layout-page)

Add to _SiteLayout:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("customHeader"))
{    
@RenderSection("customHeader")
}
else
{
@RenderPage("/shared/_header.cshtml")
}
```

Add to default page

```
@section customHeader{
This is custom header
}
```

The common header doesn't get called in the Default page, because customHeader is specified instead; whereas, all other pages use the normal header